# container exits with code 139 on my mac os M1 machine

Tags: docker, containers, podman

i am running a container on my mac os M1 machine but it exits with status code 139. I have added the --platform linux/amd64 flag but still no luck.

this is the command im running

```
podman --log-level=debug run -i -t --platform linux/amd64 --name=friends-app -p 8080:80 -e MYSQL_USER=user1 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=friends -e DBHOST=mysql --add-host=mysql:10.88.0.6 -d docker.io/swapnillinux/apache-php
INFO[0000] podman filtering at log level debug          
DEBU[0000] Called run.PersistentPreRunE(podman --log-level=debug run -i -t --platform linux/amd64 --name=friends-app -p 8080:80 -e MYSQL_USER=user1 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=friends -e DBHOST=mysql --add-host=mysql:10.88.0.6 -d docker.io/swapnillinux/apache-php) 
DEBU[0000] SSH Ident Key "/Users/bisma/.ssh/podman-machine-default" SHA256:IJ+8ffIXeHpO+qFIW0tsXtRTLInIsxBleS0peSw6gvc ssh-ed25519 
DEBU[0000] DoRequest Method: GET URI: http://d/v4.7.2/libpod/_ping 
DEBU[0000] DoRequest Method: GET URI: http://d/v4.7.2/libpod/networks/pasta/exists 
DEBU[0000] Adding port mapping from 8080 to 80 length 1 protocol "" 
DEBU[0000] Loading registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf" 
DEBU[0000] DoRequest Method: POST URI: http://d/v4.7.2/libpod/images/pull 
DEBU[0010] User or group ID mappings not available: open /proc/self/uid_map: no such file or directory 
DEBU[0010] User or group ID mappings not available: open /proc/self/uid_map: no such file or directory 
DEBU[0010] DoRequest Method: GET URI: http://d/v4.7.2/libpod/images/docker.io%2Fswapnillinux%2Fapache-php/json 
DEBU[0010] DoRequest Method: POST URI: http://d/v4.7.2/libpod/containers/create 
DEBU[0010] DoRequest Method: POST URI: http://d/v4.7.2/libpod/containers/6b379db0288ea4696cb2fe6b60dd48b155d2300f78851f88be1989abd04b8517/start 
6b379db0288ea4696cb2fe6b60dd48b155d2300f78851f88be1989abd04b8517
DEBU[0010] Called run.PersistentPostRunE(podman --log-level=debug run -i -t --platform linux/amd64 --name=friends-app -p 8080:80 -e MYSQL_USER=user1 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=friends -e DBHOST=mysql --add-host=mysql:10.88.0.6 -d docker.io/swapnillinux/apache-php) 
DEBU[0010] Shutting down engines
```

these are the running containers.

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                                   COMMAND     CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                   NAMES
5b34d10080cf  registry.access.redhat.com/rhscl/mysql-57-rhel7:latest  run-mysqld  3 hours ago  Up 3 hours  0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp  friends-db
```

this is the error log

```
bisma@Bismas-MacBook-Pro ~ % podman logs friends-app 
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 110:    11 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS "$@"
```

can someone guide please.